# Excel, Remove "/" from dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have dates in cell A4 and B4, like so

[image]

My formula in A4 is `=TEXT((Start!$D$5),"yyyymmdd")`
and my formula in B4 is `=TEXT((Start!$D$2),"yyyymmdd")`. Both are same "General" cell format.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm very confused as to why B4 has `/`.

origin of data:

Cell D2 in Start Tab:

[image]

Cell D5 in start tab:

[image]

Both have "date" as their cell format.

Here is my date settings(dont really want to change these settings)

[image]

Comment: Right click on B4 and check its date formatting.

Comment: I would bet that the "date" in `Start!$D$2` is a text string that looks like a date and not a true date.  What is your local setting for date format, `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: The format is just "general" or am I missing something?

Comment: @ScottCraner how do I check date format? I believe because I am in canada is it dd/mm/yyyy .

Comment: I assume the data is coming from somewhere else?  I will also bet that your date in A4 is incorrect in that it probably should be `20180607` and the months and days are backwards.  You will need to parse all the "dates" coming in and fix them.

Comment: I think `20180607` is wrong, It should be july. September and 2 months earlier is the start date.  I wish I could get 20180928 in cell B4.

Comment: Depending on what the origin data actually is, you could try `=TEXT((Start!$D$5),"########")`?

Comment: Didnt work :( , i added some origin data. Not sure if it will help. Im starting to think it could be that the spreadsheet was done on a US PC ? Could that affect the dates?

Comment: try this `=text(if(ISNUMBER(Start!$D$5),DATE(year(Start!$D$5),day(Start!$D$5),month(Start!$D$5)),date(right(Start!$D$5,4),left(Start!$D$5,2),mid(Start!$D$5,4,2))),"yyyymmdd")` change the D5 to D2 for the other and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Scott, This works nicely! Except for D5, it reverses to 20180607 when I want 20180706, but atleast the september 28 is working.

Comment: Are you sure? if the dates are coming in from the outside in the same format then excel is converting it incorrectly.   If you are sure then just flip `day(Start!$D$5),month(Start!$D$5)` to `month(Start!$D$5),day(Start!$D$5)`  But I think you will find that the dates coming in are all `mm/dd/yyyy` and as such `07/06/2018` is July 6th not June 7th.

Comment: @excelguy,, better update the Question and include two Screen Shots. 1. Select Cell `B4` to Show the Formula you have used. 2. Select `B4` to show the Custom Format Dialog. I do hope  Source cell `D2 & D5` has true Date Value !!

Comment: @RajeshS What do you mean true date value ?  and I assure you that b4 formula I have listed above is correct, as for the custom format dialog, I dont use custom on b4, I use "General"  format.

Comment: As @ScottCraner pointed out, the contents of D2 is really a text string and not a "real date".  You cannot have a date of `09/28/2018` with  DMY regional settings, since there are only 12 months.  How is D2 being populated? If it is being entered manually, clear the cell contents, format it as General, and then re-enter the date.  If it is the result of a formula, show us the formula.  If it from a CSV file, then you are not importing the file correctly.